# How to use facebook api with Yii?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, yii

I want to integrate facebook login with my Yii application. How can I integrate facebook api to Yii? Could not find any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/chybridauth/

---

If you don't want to use the above extension:

I suggest you follow the [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for PHP tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/). Combined with the information and example code about [Authentication and Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth) on the Yii website you should be able to create your own Facebook authentication.